# Hide / Remove .0 decimals from UISlider - Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, decimal

I am newbie to Swift 4 / Xcode development still learning almost 2 weeks, and I have problem with hiding / removing .0 from the slider value that I am trying to create. I have attached image and the code that its displayed on the app.What I am trying to do with this code is to show the number on the app without .0 like if its 15000.0 to show only 15000

```
    @IBAction func changeValueCredit(_ sender: Any) {
     let fixed = roundf((sender as AnyObject).value / 100) * 100;
     (sender as AnyObject).setValue(fixed, animated: true)
     inputValue.text = "\(creditNumber.value)" + " $ "
}
```

[image: image from the slider and the value]

Thank you all

Comment: Unrelated but `(sender as AnyObject).value` is horrible!. Declare the function `(_ sender: UISlider)` and use `sender.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `Int` to get rid of `decimal` numbers,

```
 inputValue.text = "\(Int(creditNumber.value))" + " $ "
```

Comment: For real, Thank you so much, that INT took me 2 hours from google searching lol Thank you so much

Comment: What if the number is `3.9` then? I would also at least add `+ 0.5` before converting the number into an `Int`

Comment: @JacobAhlberg you can use .roundf() I think for that. In my case the step is by 100

Comment: @JacobAhlberg Yes for that `rounded` can be used as `creditNumber.value.rounded()`

Answer (score 0):

`fixed` is a `Float` value, so it won't truncate to your desired value.
If you don't want to round it up or down, you can call:

```
@IBAction func changeValueCredit(_ sender: Any) {
     let fixed = roundf((sender as AnyObject).value / 100) * 100;
     let truncatedFixed = Int(fixed)
     (sender as AnyObject).setValue(truncatedFixed, animated: true)
     inputValue.text = "\(creditNumber.value)" + " $ "
}
```

Comment: This works to, thank you for your help, but i will keep it for more simple by now :)